# How do I adhere real cut stone the wall behind my wood stove?

Tags: tile, fireplace, masonry, stone, woodstove

We are trying to adhere real cut stones to the wall that is behind our wood stove.  The area is 7 Foot long by 5 foot high.  We are adhering the stones to Durarock, cement board.  We have placed lath on top of the Durarock and we will create a scratch coat prior.

The questions:

- Which type of mortar will give us the best adhesion?
- Do we need any other fasteners, anchors, or glue?
- Should we use the same material for the scratch coat as we would for the actual placement of the stones?

These are cut natural stones, taken from a local stone wall and cut for this purpose, one side is completely smooth.  They are very heavy.

The sizes of these stone vary from 12"x7" to 4"x4" with 2-3 inches in thickness.

Comment: 2-3 inches is awfully thick for a veneer. What's holding the wall and floor up? A wood stove is already a heavy load, adding a lot of stone weight could break things...looks like 900-1300 lbs at a rough guess. Concrete slab, no problem. Wood floor, concerning.

Comment: it is a slab , and the exterior wall is 4X6 framing,  entire area has been beefed uo to accommodate the weight ,  Just trying to find the right glue ! thank you for responding.

Comment: If they are 2" thick then they will rest on the ones below and normal brick/stone mortar should work.

Comment: I'd probably follow more of a mason type install potentially using ties to make sure the veneer can't fall off onto someone.